# Use the new value of edittext preferenceactivity in the main activity without close application

Tags: android, save, android-edittext, preferenceactivity, preference

I want to use the new value of an edittext preference that is an ip, in the main activity. I don't have to show the value in the main activity. When I try that, I only get the default value until I close and open the app again.

I only know how to save the new value just after be written.

This is the code of the main activity

```
public String IP;
public int puerto;

//Para crear el menu de settings
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;


}

//Se ponen las opciones de los iconos del menu
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.settings:
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class));
        break;

    case R.id.camera:

        break;

    case R.id.exit:
        this.finish();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return true;


}





/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    IP = preferences.getString("prefIP", "127.0.0.1");
    puerto = Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString("prefPort", "1101"));

 //After that I use the values to use a socket connection

}
```

//Preference activity code

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is, in your main activity, override `onResume()` and use it to check whether the preferences have changed:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences preferences =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String nuevoIP = preferences.getString("prefIP", "127.0.0.1");
    int nuevoPuerto = Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString("prefPort", "1101"));
    if (puerto != nuevoPuerto || !IP.equals(nuevoIP)) {
        // IP and/or puerto have changed
        IP = nuevoIP;
        puerto = nuevoPuerto;
        // close and reopen socket if appropriate
    }
}
```

This will get called whenever you return to your main activity from SettingsActivity.

If the shared preferences might change without pausing your main activity, you will have to register an [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) with the shared preferences and do the above logic there. It would then be important to unregister the listener in `onPause()` and register it in `onResume()`. You would still need to do the above check in `onResume()` because while paused it would not have been listening for changes.